# How to access photos on a DSLR camera in P2P mode

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing, camera

I'm building an app that will instantly print photos taken with DSLR camera. The idea is that I want to detect when a new photo is created on a memory card using a `FileSystemWatcher` class, and then send it to the printer. Unfortunately, I can access a memory card like this only in mass storage mode, when I can't take any new pictures. In P2P mode there is no problem with taking pictures, but I can't access the storage, as it doesn't have a drive letter assigned.

Is there any C# API that would allow me to access data on P2P device? I don't need to send any commands to it, just monitor if there are any new images and download them.

Answer (score 0):

Which DSLR do you use?

In case of Canon, the EDSDK might help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp#DownloadPhoto